# Using socket.io and express modules without npm

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, socket.io, npm

I am working on a project for an embedded Linux system (busybox made with buildroot). I am wondering if it is possible to use node.js modules *socket.io* and *express* without having to install or run `npm`. The goal is to be able to have buildroot configured to create a busybox image that simply includes node.js, and then place all my javascript files in the proper directory and execute `node app.js` from the command line to run the node application (which will use *socket.io* and *express*).

So, for example on my development machine (That does have node.js and `npm` installed), I could run `npm install socket.io` so it would get *socket.io* and all its dependencies and install it in the `node_modules` directory of my project. If I place all those files in a directory and move them to the production environment (embedded Linux with just node.js installed and where `npm install socket.io` was never run) would my application work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I place all those files in a directory and move them to the production environment would my application work?

Yes, it would. However, if you do have any binary dependencies, they need to be recompiled, so it's a bit trickier. If you don't, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to tell if a package (and all its dependencies) has binaries, or do I just have to search through all the repositories?

Comment: Run `npm rebuild`. If it's recompiling something, then binary dependencies are there. They are rare these days, I just mentioned it for the completeness sake.